# Is Lingo IRC is abandoned?

Tags: irc

I'm using nice **Lingo IRC** client, but it a bit outdated.

Links in **About** seem to be broken and I can't find this app in App Store.

Does anybody know for sure is Lingo IRC abandoned?

Maybe there is a way to contact with maintainer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments at [MacUpdate for Lingo](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/48886/lingo), the product appears to have been removed the Mac App Store and is no longer being maintained.

The domain associated with Lingo IRC, http://lingoirc.com, is now a holding page.